# error C4996: visual studio: why do I get an error when I use fopen in c?

Tags: c, visual-studio, file

I just started to work with files so I made this program that just opens a file but i get the error:

```
error C4996: 'fopen': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using fopen_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
```

here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE* f = fopen("myFile.txt", "w");
    if (f == NULL)
    {
        printf("error\n");
        return;
    }
    fclose(f);
}
```

Comment: Just put `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` before `#include <stdio.h>`

Comment: that solved it! thanks!

Comment: Simply typing the error message into a Google or SO search field immediately shows that the question has been asked (and answered!) many times.

Comment: Alternatively, get a better C compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to place a definition of `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE` before your include. Like,

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
#include <stdio.h>
```