# What is wrong with accessing this private variable of class by a private method?

Tags: c++

What I am trying to do is to parse a csv file into a dynamically allocated part of a memory that represents an array of instances of a class called rectangle.

The project consists of the following files:

**rectStructs.h:**

```
#pragma once

struct rectangle_t
{
    int length;
    int width;
};
```

**rectangles.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>

#include "rectStructs.h"

using namespace std;

class rectangle
{
public:
    rectangle(int length, int width);
    unsigned long int get_area();
private:
    rectangle_t _rectangle;
};
```

**rectangles.cpp**

```
#include "rectangles.h"
#include <string> 

rectangle::rectangle(int RectLength, int RectWidth)
{
    _rectangle.length = RectLength;
    _rectangle.width = RectWidth;
}

unsigned long int rectangle::get_area()
{
    return _rectangle.length * _rectangle.width;
}
```

**rectanglesSet.h**

```
#pragma once

#include "rectangles.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

class rectangleSet
{
public:
    rectangleSet(string path_sourceCSV);
    rectangle getRect(unsigned int RectIndex);
private:
    void readRectsFromCSV(rectangle** rectangles, string path_sourceCSV);
    rectangle* _rectangles;
    unsigned int _rectCount;
    rectangle _getRect(rectangle** rectangles, unsigned int RectIndex);
};
```

**rectanglesSet.cpp**

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE // For using fopen and strtok https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42412372/error-c4996-visual-studio-why-do-i-get-an-error-when-i-use-fopen-in-c

#include "rectanglesSet.h"

void rectangleSet::readRectsFromCSV(rectangle** rectangles, string path_sourceCSV)
{
    unsigned short int _linesCount = 0;

    //Parsing lt. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56783258/parse-csv-into-dynamically-allocated-array-of-structures-ansi-89

    char c;

    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen(path_sourceCSV.c_str(), "r");             /* Open the saleslines file */

    if (fp == NULL) {                              /* Crash if file not found */
        printf("Error - file not found\n");
    }

    c = getc(fp);
    while (c != EOF) {
        if (c == '\n') {
            _linesCount++;
        }
        c = getc(fp);
    }
    fclose(fp);

    cout << "Number of lines: " << _linesCount << endl;   //Debug

    *rectangles = (rectangle*)malloc((_linesCount + 1) * sizeof(rectangle));

    int _length;
    int _width;

    /* allocation of the buffer for every line in the File */
    char buf[1024];
    string tmp;

    if ((fp = fopen(path_sourceCSV.c_str(), "r")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("File could not be opened.\n");
    }
    int line = 0;
    while (fgets(buf, 1024, fp) != NULL)
    {
        if ((strlen(buf) > 0) && (buf[strlen(buf) - 1] == '\n'))
            buf[strlen(buf) - 1] = '\0';

        if (line > 0) // First line is header
        {
            tmp = strtok(buf, ",");
            _length = atoi(tmp.c_str());

            tmp = strtok(NULL, ",");
            _width = atoi(tmp.c_str());

            rectangles[line - 1] = new rectangle(_length, _width);

            //Debug
            cout << rectangles[line - 1]->get_area() << endl;
        }

        line++;
    }
    fclose(fp);

    //_rectCount = line - 1;

    cout << "Successfully parsed: " << path_sourceCSV << endl;
}

rectangleSet::rectangleSet(string path_sourceCSV)
{
    readRectsFromCSV(&_rectangles, path_sourceCSV);
}

rectangle rectangleSet::_getRect(rectangle** rectangles, unsigned int rectIndex)
{
    return *rectangles[rectIndex];
}

rectangle rectangleSet::getRect(unsigned int rectIndex)
{
    return _getRect(&_rectangles, rectIndex);
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "rectangles.h"
#include "rectanglesSet.h"

int main()
{
    string str_SourceCSV = "C:\\rectangleList.csv";
    rectangleSet* _rectangleSet = new rectangleSet(str_SourceCSV);

    cout << _rectangleSet->getRect(1).get_area() << endl;
}
```

**C:\rectangleList.csv**

```
x,y
1,2
3,4
5,6
```

Everything works perfectly fine, as long as I comment out the following line in the file **rectanglesSet.cpp**

```
//_rectCount = line - 1;
```

It is supposed to write a private variable holding the number of items in the dynamic array _rectangles. When I uncomment this line the program crashes with a memory error. It runs to the point of displaying the second item ([1]) of the object _rectangleSet.

What is wrong with this line?

```
_rectCount = line - 1;
```

Comment: Do you really need all that code to reproduce the problem you face? Please post a [mcve] (emphasis on ***minimal***), which demonstrates your problem. Ty.

Comment: How about `std::vector<rectangle>` instead of manual memory management?

Comment: Please note that the solution does not belong in the question. It should be posted as a proper answer. If you'd like to answer your own question, you can do so. Please re-take the site [tour].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are allocating an array of rectangles here

```
*rectangles = (rectangle*)malloc((_linesCount + 1) * sizeof(rectangle));
```

but then you are treating it as if you had an array of rectangle pointers here

```
rectangles[line - 1] = new rectangle(_length, _width);
```

The correct code for the above line is

```
(*rectangles)[line - 1] = rectangle(_length, _width);
```

However even with this fix you are still technically wrong because the above line assigns to uninitialised memory (returned by `malloc`). So the first line should really be using `new` instead to make sure the rectangle array is properly initialised.

```
*rectangles = new rectangle[_linesCount + 1];
```

C++ is a lot easier if you don't try to do your own memory management. Instead of the above code I recommend that you use `std::vector<rectangle>`. It would be a lot more efficient as well, because you could use the `vector::push_back` method so you don't have to precalculate the number of lines and so you avoid reading the input file twice.